# Database connection from php container with host name "localhost" instead of container name

Tags: php, mysql, docker

Our website-framework(s) are designed to work on both xampp and docker environments. We are recognizing our database hosts by host name/IP-address (dev, test, staging, live env). People who are working with xampp are using `https://localhost`, so they get the environment variable called `Development`. People who are working with docker are using `https://docker` as their host. They get the env-variable called `Development/Docker`. We need this differentiation because inside the php applications our xampp users are connecting to their mysql service with host `localhost`. Docker users have to connect via host called `mysql` (this is the container name of the mysql-service).

> Because of the last occurred problems (not relevant to be mentioned here) we want a unique solution for both user-groups concerning the database connection: Docker users should be able to connect to their mysql service with host `localhost`.

`docker-compose.yaml` (shortened for better overview):

```
version: '2'
services:
  #######################################
  # PHP application Docker container
  #######################################
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    links:
      - mail
      - mysql
      - redis
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "10022:22"
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
      - ./:/docker/
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    env_file:
      - etc/environment.yml
      - etc/environment.development.yml
    environment:
      - POSTFIX_RELAYHOST=[mail]:1025

  #######################################
  # MySQL server
  #######################################
  mysql:
    build:
      context: docker/mysql/
      dockerfile: MariaDB-10.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - etc/environment.yml
      - etc/environment.development.yml

  #######################################
  # phpMyAdmin
  #######################################
  # /// #

  #######################################
  # Mail
  #######################################
  # /// #

  #######################################
  # Redis
  #######################################
  # /// #

# Volumes
volumes:
  mysql:
  phpmyadmin:
  redis:
```

I tried a lot and played with the docker-compose but didn't find a solution for weeks. Tried with links, networks and so on. I think my docker skills are exhausted by now...

I also added to the `mysql.conf`:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: suppose you are able to access mysql service as a `localhost`, then how you will access the `app` ? so one way to install mysql in your current docker image.

Comment: You can’t use `localhost` as an arbitrary placeholder for a host name.  In a Docker context it almost always means “this container” and nothing else.  In the same way you have configuration for a remote SMTP server, you should add configuration for the location of your database server.  (Imagine using a hosted database solution like Amazon’s RDS: you wouldn’t expect the database hostname to be `localhost` ever in that environment and you’d need some way to configure it.)

Comment: `app` listens on port `80/443` and can be reached over the browser via `127.0.0.1` (or any other domain registered in the hosts file). I have thought the same way and the only logical conclusion is that the mysql service can be reached via port `3306` and host "localhost". But according to my research, both are encapsulated services that can only communicate with each other via container names. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of docker's networking structure.

docker creates 3 base interfaces. `docker0` , `host` and `none`.

each container uses docker0 by default. then each container will have a virtual network interface for communicating between containers. so you can use your database with `mysql` address.

if you want to connect to database with address `localhost` you should config docker to use `host` network mode (you can do it by adding one line to defenition of your app service in docker compose file). it will be able to connect to every app which is running on your system. By the way you would loose communication with other container by their name. maybe you loose your connection with your redis (which is connected with `redis` address)

In this network mode, every dependency should be deployed or be exposed to your localhost.

Comment: did you mean this https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/?

Comment: I mean adding `network_mode: host` to your docker compose app service

Comment: I added `network_mode: host` and `network: host` inside `build` context to both webserver and mysql-server. No IP for these services listet when running `docker ps` (seems correct to me). Checked IP by typing `hostname -i` inside webserver container - tried to open this IP inside browser and also pinged via console but got no response...